# How to search text in all database objects in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am able search in procedures and triggers for exact text within the `""` .
But i need to search a string within the `%%` for all phrases in all database objects

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, not sure if you mean "within procedures and functions I can search for exact text" `or` "I can search procedures and functions for exact text".... either way, the keyword you're looking for is `LIKE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUTINE_TYPE,* FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE 
CHARINDEX( 'test',ROUTINE_DEFINITION)>0

SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION,* FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE 
CHARINDEX('test',VIEW_DEFINITION)>0

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
(CHARINDEX( 'col1',COLUMN_NAME)>0 OR CHARINDEX( 'tab2',TABLE_NAME)>0)
```

Instead of like operator with Percentile (Like '%test%') we used charindex  to improve the performance of search

Comment: Can you share how you tested for performance improvement? Genuinely interested.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from sys.sql_modules 
where definition like '%test%'
```

some info about SYS.SQL_Modules

> Returns a row for each object that is an SQL language-defined module in SQL Server, including natively compiled scalar user-defined function. Objects of type P, RF, V, TR, FN, IF, TF, and R have an associated SQL module

with sp_msfporeachDB, you can test it in all databases;

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 

if db_id()>4'
Begin
select * from sys.sql_modules where defintion like ''%test%''
end
```